# Custom Tax Archive of Parents Only?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Is it possible to have a page which shows a list of the custom tax parents only and only 1 post per custom tax, i/e link to the parent archive

So even though the custom tax may have x number of posts and x number of child custom tax's its basically just showing a link to that custom tax archive page parent.

SO essentially an archive page just for the custom tax parents ignoring the posts within.

I can do this manually with a page template and query each custom tax individually but wondered if it could be done dynamically.

I have the following but its spitting out all the posts within the category. Perhaps get_terms is needed i'm not sure?

```
<?php

                    $args = array(
                       'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_type' => 'product',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product-area',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => array('insulation','drylining-plastering'),
                                        'include_children' => false
                                    )
                                )
                    );
                    $products_tax = new WP_Query( $args );


                   if($products_tax->have_posts()) : 
                      while($products_tax->have_posts()) : 
                         $products_tax->the_post();
                ?>

                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a></h2>


                <?php
                      endwhile;
                   else: 
                ?>

                      Oops, there are no posts.

                <?php
                   endif; 
                   wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure this out myself, so if anyone out there needs some help please try the following...

Using the get_terms rather than trying to query it directly.

```
<?php 

                    $terms = get_terms('custom-tax-name', array('hierarchical' => false));
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {


                    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

                     if ( have_posts() ) :

                 ?>


                     <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
                     <?php echo '<h3>'.$term->name.'</h3>'; ?>


                    </a>

                <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); } ?>
```